# Not able to format Pendrive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive

I have a pendrive with fat32 partition and have some data.

Whenever I tried to format this pendrive, it didn't format. 
I've tried to format with `gparted`, and it shows an successful message.

But after that, pendrive is not formatting it came in previous format (`fat32`) with same data.
So, How can I solve this problem ?

[pendrive]
[image: pendrive image]

Any kind help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) may help you to analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, to solve it.